# How to create jni header file with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, c++, intellij-idea, header, java-native-interface

I want to create the head file in IntelliJ IDEA. This is the way I do it:

file>setting>Tools>External Tools

then I click +, specify the title and set the parameters as follow:

Program: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin

Parameters: -d C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\JniExampleLibrary -jni Example.JniExample

Working Directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin

but after clicking ok, there is no JniExample.h file in the path defined above with -d

Would you please tell me what is the problem with it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't the program be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\javah`? (your description is missing the actual command to run)

Comment: Hi. I fixed the program to contain javah, but again the head file was not created. any other idea?

Answer (score 32):

Here are the IntelliJ IDEA settings I use to generate the .h file:
(This applies to IDEA version 12.1.6, probably similar in other versions)

1. File->Settings->External Tools
2. Click the + button for the "Edit Tool" dialog
3. The following are the form name/value pairs I used:

   - Name: **javah**
   - Group: **Java**
   - Description: **Java Native Interface C Header and Stub File Generator**
   - Options: Check All
   - Show in: Check All
   - Tool Settings...
   - Program: **$JDKPath$\bin\javah.exe**
   - Parameters: **-jni -v -d $FileDir$ $FileClass$**
   - Working directory: **$SourcepathEntry$**
4. Click OK, Click OK
5. Navigate to your java class with the native method
6. With the java class being shown in the editor, go to **Tools->Java->javah**
7. Notice the .h file that was generated in the same directory as your class.

Comment: Just tested this out in IntelliJ 2017.2 on Mac OS. I can confirm it still works great!

Comment: This is fantastic.  I always used to hate remembering how to fire off a javah with all the pathing.

Comment: Starting from JDK 8, use `javac -h` instead of `javah`. Parameters/Arguments: `-h . $FileDir$/$FileName$`

Comment: For those who needs classpath dependencies, use the following parameters/argument: `-jni -d "$FileDir$" -classpath "$Classpath$" $FileClass$`

Answer (score 8):

I am using Java 11 (OpenJDK) to compile, so I do not have javah available.

Since now the option to create header files is included in javac, I added it as an compiler option.

1. File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler->Java Compiler
2. In "Additional command line parameters" add: -h YourOutDir

(IntelliJ Community 2019.2, other versions should be similar)

Example:

```
-h C:/Development/Java/YourApp/cpp
```

I did not have any luck with "-h $FileDir$" or other macro commands of IntelliJ.